# How to add padding to the text inside nodes?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, graph-layout, msagl

Does MSAGL (Microsoft automatic graph layout) have functionality for padding? All the text on the nodes are hugging the corners/boundaries of the nodes.

I tried adding spaces to the left and right sides of the text, but it only works on the left side and not on the right.

```
    string paddedLabel = "   " + uri.Host + "   "; // spaces for horizontal padding
    msaglNode.LabelText = paddedLabel;
```